# Does XOR of message $m$ with $\mathrm{Enc}$ leak any information?

Tags: encryption, one-time-pad

Let's suppose that $(G,D,E)$ is a secure encryption scheme, that is, for any polynomial $p(n)$ and any sequence of messages $\{a_{n}\},\;\{b_{n}\}$ of length $p(n)$ $E(k,a_{n})$ and $E(k,b_{n})$ are computationally indistinguishable.

Is $E'(k,m) = E(k,m)\oplus m$ also a secure "encryption algorithm"? Sure, in some cases this is not even encryption, e. g. consider $E(k,m) = k\oplus m$. Then $E'$ just erases the message, but still doesn't give anything to an attacker. But what if this "scheme" (even though, not an encryption scheme, possibly) was insecure, leaking some substantial information to an attacker? Then we would have some sequences $\{a_{n}\},\;\{b_{n}\}$ (as above) such that some PPT $\mathcal{A}$ could distinguish $E(k,a_{n})\oplus a_{n}$ and $E(k,b_{n})\oplus b_{n}$. This sequences could be hardwared to some scheme, that works as that distinguisher $\mathcal{A}$. Xoring these messages with known (to this scheme) $a_{n},b_{n}$ gives $E(k,\cdot)$, so the algorithm can now distinguish $E(k,a_{n})$ and $E(k,b_{n})$, contradicting the fact, that $(G,D,E)$ is secure. Am I right?

Comment: I wouldn't consider it an "encryption algorithm", because (in general) there's no way to decrypt.

Comment: that's what I said in the problem. so let's consider it just some scheme

Comment: It looks like an algorithm obtaining information about m from E(k,m)⊕m could be turned into an algorithm that breaks E under the CPA experiment. If I'm correct, E wouldn't be secure under Chosen Plaintext Attack.

Comment: I would argue that if $E$ is a block cipher then $m$ would be secure to a certain extent even though it would obviously not be IND-CPA. But yeah, if you have one method that is relatively secure, another that isn't and no way to descrypt then it becomes too hard a problem to make anything out of it.